# React Native Metro Bundler not starting automatically

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm using mx Linux which is  Ubuntu derivation. Trying to use react-native with genymotion. I did all installation right I suppose.

Android studio latest with some SDK.

Configured PATH like

```
    export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Nodejs version 10.21.0 (tried 12.4.0 and latest also.But result is same )
npm version 5.8.0 (tried newests but same)

Genymotion settings (For SDK path ) done like that

```
 /home/kaan/Android/Sdk/


    $ npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.

> Task :app:installDebug
01:50:49 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
01:50:49 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on '192.168.56.101:5555' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:50:49 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Samsung Galaxy S6 - 5.0' for app:debug
01:50:49 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device '192.168.56.101:5555'
01:50:49 D/Device: Uploading file onto device '192.168.56.101:5555'
01:50:49 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /home/kaan/Rn/first/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rw-r--r--
01:50:49 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
01:50:52 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '192.168.56.101:5555' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:50:52 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:50:52 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
01:50:52 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '192.168.56.101:5555' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:50:52 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "192.168.56.101:5555"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.first/.MainActivity }
kaan@development:~/Rn/first
$
```

And here is the result. Metro bundler didn't run as aspected as automatically.

I started npx react-native start its working but
when I change something it's not updating because npx react-native run-android finished as you see on top.

Did anyone face this problem before ?
And anyone can solve this?

Comment: are u solve it?

Comment: Yes i start metro manually

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running the packager in a different port? If not try this

Running packager on different port

```
npx react-native start --port 8084 --reset-cache
```

After that run

```
  react-native run-android --port 8084
```

in second command prompt window.

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. with various of ports 8888, 4444 etc but result same nothing changed. it compiles but metro bundler not working automatically. and no error also

Comment: What is the node version that you are using?

Comment: I used 10.x 12.x and latest stable.. all 3 failed

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution except running metro bundler manually. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can solve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/77644306/9888280