# Metro bundler starts and then stops during "react-native run-android" command process

Tags: android, react-native, metro-bundler

I have been developing an application in react native for about 2 years. Before, running and updating the app worked without any issues. I don't know at what point in development **Metro bundler** started to stop when running `npx react-native run-android`. When I run this command, it does all its processing and also launches a window with **Metro bundler** (but in the middle of the process this window closes) and finally installs and launches the app on the mobile device. This is quite inconvenient, since to verify a small change I have to run the command `npx react-native bundle`* and then again `npx react-native run-android`. This means that to verify some changes I have to wait 3 or 4 minutes.

*Bundle command: `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

My development environment and other information:

- OS: Windows 10.
- Code editor: Visual Studio Code.
- Project RN version: 0.67.2.

I have tried to do the following without getting a solution:

- Run `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ../` command.
- Remove node_modules folder and run `npm install` command.

In case it helps `npx react-native run-android` command output:

```
> AppName@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

warn Package @react-native-masked-view/masked-view has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module '@react-native-masked-view\masked-view\package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-tools\build\resolveNodeModuleDir.js
- C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-tools\build\releaseChecker\index.js
- C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-tools\build\index.js
- C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\resolveNodeModuleDir.js
- C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\resolveReactNativePath.js
- C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\index.js
- C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\install\install.js
- C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
- C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
- C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1282 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\navigation_json\debug\navigation.json'. Reason: Task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:processDebugManifest
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:processDebugManifest' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\compatible_screen_manifest\debug'. Reason: Task ':app:processDebugManifest' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml'. Reason: Task ':app:processDebugManifest' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:compressDebugAssets' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets'. Reason: Task ':app:compressDebugAssets' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:processDebugManifestForPackage' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug'. Reason: Task ':app:processDebugManifestForPackage' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\java_res\debug\out'. Reason: Task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\duplicate_classes_check\debug'. Reason: Task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\duplicate_classes_check\debug'. Reason: Task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug'. Reason: Task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_jni_libs\debug\out'. Reason: Task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\DATA\Projects\ProjectName\Code\AppName\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\debug\out'. Reason: Task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols' uses this output of task ':app:copyDebugIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:installDebug
Installing APK 'com.appname-2.5-29-debug.apk' on 'SM-A530F - 9' for :app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 9 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 1s
293 actionable tasks: 11 executed, 282 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "5200ba9a5e7cc481"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.appname/.MainActivity }
```

**Edit:**

I have been able to capture the error trace of the Metro window. The error occurs when the trace `> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols` is output in the window where `npx react-native run-android` is executed. In case it helps.

```
To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

C:\...\MyProyectName\node_modules\metro-hermes-compiler\src\emhermesc.js:77
           throw ex;
           ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\...\MyProyectName\android\app\build\intermediates\stripped_native_libs\debug\out\lib\armeabi-v7a\libevent_extra-2.1.so.tmp1e1f3c7'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.<anonymous> (C:\...\MyProyectName\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:291:16)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:207:21) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'C:\\...\\MyProyectName\\android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\stripped_native_libs\\debug\\out\\lib\\armeabi-v7a\\libevent_extra-2.1.so.tmp1e1f3c7'
  
Node.js v18.13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue plus metro shell window stopped to show console log from app.

I solved the issue by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true` to the "application" section of `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I am already using this property since long time. So it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/484
Please take a look here

Answer (score 0):

I am on react native version `0.73.0`. I found this commmand which will automatically start the Metro Server as well as run on android:

```
npx react-native start run-android
```

I hope this answer helps someone who is facing the same problem.

Comment: react-native version 0.73.0 just be released last week. I don't think version 0.75.0 is exist

Comment: sorry my bad, its 0.73.0. Thanks for correction @DinhNguyen